# How do I tell Applescript to tell Acrobat to click the don't save button if/when it appears

Tags: applescript, acrobat, filesystem-events

Heres my code.  Works fine as long as its a PDF. but if it opens a JPEG after the command window close a new dialog box pops up and asks if I want to save the document as a PDF. I just want to tell it to click don't save and move on... Can't figure it out..

```
tell application "Adobe Acrobat Pro"
        activate -- bring up acrobat
        open alias mycurrentfile -- acrobat opens that new file    
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "Acrobat"
                click menu item "Print..." of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
                click button "Print" of window "Print"
                tell application "System Events"
                    tell process "Acrobat"
                        click menu item "Close" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1

                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tell application "Adobe Acrobat Pro"
    activate -- bring up acrobat
    open alias mycurrentfile -- acrobat opens that new file    
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Acrobat"
            click menu item "Print..." of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
            click button "Print" of window "Print"
        end tell
    end tell
    close document 1 without saving
end tell
```

if you're just looking to print pdf it might be better to just use preview

```
set mycurrentfile to choose file
tell application "Preview"
    print mycurrentfile without print dialog
end tell
```

Comment: @drbronze did you end up just using preview ?